# how to call angular2 method after resolving jQuery promise

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Third party Library [MarvinJS](https://chemaxon.com/products/marvin-js) in my Angular5 Application. I 
need to call a method `this.sharedService.openMarvinModal(false);`  after resolving the MarvinJS promise.

When I invoke the method, it is giving error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'sharedService' of undefined
at eval (marvin-modal.component.ts:58)
at <anonymous>
```

Code Snippet:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from "@angular/core";

import { SharedService } from "../services/shared.service";

import * as $ from "jquery";
declare var MarvinJSUtil: any;

@Component({
  selector: "app-marvin-modal",
  templateUrl: "./marvin-modal.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./marvin-modal.component.scss"]
})
export class MarvinModalComponent
  implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getStructure() {
    const p  = MarvinJSUtil.getEditor("#sketch");
    p.then(function(sketchInstance) {
      sketchInstance.exportStructure("smiles").then(function( source) {
        console.log(source);
        this.sharedService.openMarvinModal(false);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

How can I get around this issue? Any one can please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace the 2 `functions` you have with arrow notation

Comment: Thanks all for your quick response. I have changed both  `functions` to arrow notation, it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `function` with simple `arrow function` - to not create another context to which `this` refers.

```
p.then((sketchInstance) => {
   sketchInstance.exportStructure("smiles").then((source) => {
      console.log(source);
      this.sharedService.openMarvinModal(false);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response @Suren Srapyan It's working perfectly.